# Is it ok having a ground wiring loose in the light fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting

There is a ground wire coming from the box and is attached to the green screw (grounded). There is also a ground wire coming out of the light fixture loose and not connected to anything. Is this ok?

Answer (score 5):

No. If a ground wire is present, it has an intended function.

Pigtail the lamp and box wires together with the grounding conductor in the cable.